# bittorrent webseed with authentication

Tags: bittorrent, http-authentication, seeding, webtorrent

I am designing a platform for serving media content for media makers, that works with web torrent. But for premium users we want serve high availability of content  (for old media, that maybe has not seeds) using http seeds (web seeds) with BEP0019 standard (http://www.getright.com/seedtorrent.html). Obviously premium users needs an authentication method for webseeds. I think that http authentication maybe works for it, but I was researching and I have not found some way to authenticate and secure the http seeds in way that only premium users has access.

Also I don't want overlook that availability must be in browser and torrent client.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatives to basic auth are:

- IP whitelisting whenever the user logs into your website. This may be an issue for users that run a torrent client on a server, so you should at least offer a login API that can be `curl`'d.
- embed a login token into the /path/ segment of the URL. but practically that is not much different from basic auth

Comment: I think that token could be the better solution. I will think about and research a little more this approach.